# assign key and value while provsioing azure keyvault

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, azure-keyvault, devops-services

All I am provisioning azure key vault by terraform. Is there any way to set key and value  during provision not after provision. My requirement is some sort of custome key and value should set during provision and utlize in other module.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "test" {
  name                     = "storageaccountname"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location                 = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "${var.azurerm_resource_group_name}"
  location = "${var.location}"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "test" {
  name                        = "${var.azurerm_key_vault}"
  location                    = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name         = "${var.azurerm_resource_group_name}"
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = "${var.tenant_id}"

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = "${var.tenant_id}"
    object_id = "${var.object_id}"

    key_permissions = [
      "get",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "get",
    ]

    storage_permissions = [
      "get",
    ]
  }

  network_acls {
    default_action = "Allow"
    bypass         = "AzureServices"
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.tags_environment}"
  }
}
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [azurerm_key_vault_secret](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/key_vault_secret.html) to set a secret using Terraform

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "test" {
  name         = "secret-sauce"
  value        = "szechuan"
  key_vault_id = "${azurerm_key_vault.test.id}"

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to me, your suggestion will work for one key, imagine if I have 10 keys in case I have to repeat 10 times azurerm_key_vault_secret. Please suggest

Comment: @VijayVerma see this [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/8573), few examples in there of creating resources iteratively.

Comment: thanks for pointing me that works. Is it possible to access multiple keys as data source in other resources. I mean I am deploying kafka and accessing multiple key from azure key vault but the mentioned code is not working. `data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "userlist" {
 
   name   = "acctestusrgw"
   values = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id}"
  
   name   = "acctestusrvm"
  values = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id}"
  }`

Comment: @VijayVerma I think we are getting beyond the scope of the original question now, please ask a new question if you have a different issue

Comment: sure james. I asked as new question